# How to return the grub-pc screen in the upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upgrade

I have a triple boot system with Ubuntu(16.04), Kali Linux, and Windows 7.
I was upgrading Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 and the window for the grub configuration froze after I chose to open a new shell, so I did close the window and now the upgrade just stopped in this step and waiting for command.

So what I can do?
This where the installation stopped:

[image: This where the installation stopped]